# Wordpress replace default width and height values for images

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I want to replace the default `width` and `height` values that are added by the visual editor in Wordpress.

I am using the `add_filter` function:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );
```

and my function is:

```
function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
  $html = preg_replace( '/\s*(?:(?:width=|height=)"(\d*)")/', 'style="max-width: ${1}px; max-height: ${2}px;"', $html );    
  return $html;
}
```

Input string is:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" alt="" width="300" height="71" class="random-class pull-left" />
```

May also contain `a` tags wrapped around.

I want the output to be:

```
<img ..... style="max-width: 300px; max-height: 71px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using alternation, just match the width then height and capture the digits.

```
$html = preg_replace('/width="(\d+)"\s*height="(\d+)"/', 'style="max-width: $1px; max-height: $2px;"', $html);
```